# Image added in Image control displays in smaller size at runtime vb6

Tags: vb6

I have used some images inside image controls in my form. Even though the images are displayed fine in design time (32 * 32 px, 48 * 48 px) and running through the code,  After I create the .dll file of the project and run with word (My project is working with MS word), the image displayed in smaller in size.

I have tried with different image formats that are supportive with Image controls, but issue is still the same. Also I have set the stretch = true for Image controller, then the image is cracked in run time. So I tried with bigger size images like 64 * 64 px, 128 * 128 px. But they are also cracked in run time.

In design time image is displayed as follows :

[image]

In run time, it displays as follows :

[image]

I am very glad if anyone can help me with this. 
Thank you.

Comment: What "image controllers" are you talking about?  Maybe you mean "Image controls?"  No idea what you are trying to do, but it could easily be a DPI Scaling issue.

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. It is 'Image control'. Now I have corrected it and added some images, hope you can understand the scenario now.